# Flutter Dio Networking: SSL pinning using certificate's public hashed key string (not a file)

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I currently use the following snippet to include my SSL certificate file into the http client:

```
final List<int>? _certBytes; //I read it from .cer file included in the project

(_dio.httpClientAdapter as DefaultHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate =
        (client) {
      if (_certBytes != null) {
        SecurityContext sc = SecurityContext();
        sc.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(_certBytes!);
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient(context: sc);
        return httpClient;
      } else {
        client.badCertificateCallback =
            ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);
        return client;
      }
    };
```

while this code works well, it will stop working if the certificate is expired, which means that I need to add a new certificate file into the app and upload again to the app stores, so I decided to host the certificate as a hashed string in Firebase's `Remote Config` and read it upon app launch, so I can change the certificate remotely without building new versions for the app, but couldn't find a way to set the `SecurityContext` with a certificate hashed string in the `Dio`'s `HTTPClient`

Comment: In the `badCertificateCallback` you are given the server's certificate in the first parameter. It has a `sha1` getter. If you end up in the callback (maybe the cert has expired) you can compare it with the hash. (Heads up, the certificate passed as `cert` doesn't always seem to be the leaf. The boringssl lower layers seem to deliver the intermediate certificate sometimes. Really the callback should be of the whole chain not just one certificate.)

Comment: yeah that's true, but I don't wanna rely on the bad callback in order to check validity, I want a way to set that hash into the client itself